# Execute exe file with parameters using WIX Bootstrapper

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.7

I want to Execute an exe file say sample.exe by passing parameters using Bootstrapper. Problem is bootstrapper application fails to execute the exe. 
Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

I have a bat file containing:

```
start /d "D:\Setup\DBInstaller\bin\Release" DBInstaller.exe
```

and my code on Bundle.wxs is

```
<ExePackage Id="ExecuteScripts" 
  Vital="yes" 
  InstallCondition="RadioButton3 = 1" 
  Permanent="yes" 
  PerMachine="yes" 
  SourceFile="$(var.dir)ExecuteScripts.bat" 
  InstallCommand="&quot;[WixBundleLastUsedSource]DBInstaller.exe&quot; D:\Setup\DatabaseSettings.xml" 
  DetectCondition="true"> 
</ExePackage>
```

I am sending the path of an XML file as a parameter.

ERROR MSG : Invalid Function

Comment: Check the bootstrapper log in your `%TEMP%` folder.

Comment: Already Checked. It is not getting Parameter. And i have already passed parameter using InstallCommand in ExePackage.

Comment: I have a bat file start /d "D:\Setup\DBInstaller\bin\Release" DBInstaller.exe and my code on Bundle.wxs is        <ExePackage Id="ExecuteScripts" Vital="yes" InstallCondition="RadioButton3 = 1" Permanent="yes" PerMachine="yes"
                  SourceFile="$(var.dir)ExecuteScripts.bat" InstallCommand="&quot;[WixBundleLastUsedSource]DBInstaller.exe&quot; D:\Setup\DatabaseSettings.xml" DetectCondition="true">
      </ExePackage>                                                                                                                            I am sending the path of xml as parameter

Comment: What does the log actually say about the ExecuteScripts package? Is ExececuteScripts.bat being run? Please edit the question to add the information.